# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

Given the following:

```
a = 23
b = 45
c = 16

round((a/b)*0.9*c)
```

Running the above outputs an error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.
```

How can I round the output to an integer?

Comment: I think your problem is somewhere else than in the code shown.

Comment: Very similar: [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](/q/31087111/4518341)

Comment: The code runs fine.

Comment: I had similar error in code "for i in range(x, y)" - the issue was that I created variable named range, so quite maybe you made somewhere variable called round

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Somewhere else in your code you have something that looks like this:

```
round = 42
```

Then when you write

```
round((a/b)*0.9*c)
```

that is interpreted as meaning a function call on the object bound to `round`, which is an `int`. And that fails.

The problem is whatever code binds an `int` to the name `round`. Find that and remove it.

Comment: to make a long story short: do not name a var and a function equal.

Comment: Ah the old `false = true` problem.  This one caught me too.  python is a tricky (and slippery) mistress.

Answer (score 16):

I got the same error (TypeError: 'int' object is not callable)

```
def xlim(i,k,s1,s2):
   x=i/(2*k)
   xl=x*(1-s2*x-s1*(1-x)) / (1-s2*x**2-2*s1*x(1-x))
   return xl 
... ... ... ... 

>>> xlim(1,100,0,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 3, in xlim
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

after reading this post I realized that I forgot a multiplication sign * so

```
def xlim(i,k,s1,s2):
   x=i/(2*k)
   xl=x*(1-s2*x-s1*(1-x)) / (1-s2*x**2-2*s1*x * (1-x))
   return xl 

xlim(1.0,100.0,0.0,0.0)
0.005
```

tanks

Comment: It was actually a different problem. See the accepted answer.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago but this answered actually solved my problem. Vote up from me

Comment: For me, this should have been the answer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Stop stomping on `round` somewhere else by binding an `int` to it.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing this issue but in a little different scenario.

Scenario:

```
param = 1

def param():
    .....
def func():
    if param:
        var = {passing a dict here}
        param(var)
```

It looks simple and a stupid mistake here, but due to multiple lines of codes in the actual code, it took some time for me to figure out that the variable name I was using was same as my function name because of which I was getting this error.

Changed function name to something else and it worked.

So, basically, according to what I understood, this error means that you are trying to use an integer as a function or in more simple terms, the called function name is also used as an integer somewhere in the code.
So, just try to find out all occurrences of the called function name and look if that is being used as an integer somewhere.

I struggled to find this, so, sharing it here so that someone else may save their time, in case if they get into this issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons for this error "**TypeError: 'int' object is not callable**"

1. **Function Has an Integer Value**

Consider

```
a = [5, 10, 15, 20]
max = 0
max = max(a)
print(max)
```

This will produce TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

Just change the variable name "max" to var(say).

```
a = [5, 10, 15, 20]
var = 0
var = max(a)
print(var)
```

The above code will run perfectly without any error!!

2. **Missing a Mathematical Operator**

Consider

```
a = 5
b = a(a+1)
print(b)
```

This will also produce TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

You might have forgotten to put the operator in between ( '*' in this case )

Comment: Of course, traditional mathematical notation allows you to omit the multiplication sign in cases like this; but then, traditional mathematical notation would use single-letter variable names. If putting two expressions next to each other were to imply multiplication, you would be unable to distinguish between `max` the function name and `m*a*x` (and `m*ax`, and `ma*x`)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I changed:

```
return <variable>
```

with:

```
return str(<variable>)
```

try with the following and it must work:

```
str(round((a/b)*0.9*c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the problem would be forgetting an operator while calculation.

Example:
`print(n-(-1+(math.sqrt(1-4(2*(-n))))/2))` rather 
it has to be 
`print(n-(-1+(math.sqrt(1-4*(2*(-n))))/2))`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you might have a variable named round (of type `int`) in your code and removing that should get rid of the error. For Jupyter notebooks however, simply clearing a cell or deleting it might not take the variable out of scope. In such a case, you can restart your notebook to start afresh after deleting the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the below method to disambiguate the function.

```
__import__('__builtin__').round((a/b)*0.9*c)
```

`__builtin__` is the module name for all the built in functions like round, min, max etc. Use the appropriate module name for functions from other modules.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error because I was calling a function inside my model that used the [@property decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

```
@property
def volume_range(self):
    return self.max_oz - self.min_oz
```

When I tried to call this method in my serializer, I hit the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable".

```
    def get_oz_range(self, obj):
      return obj.volume_range()
```

In short, the issue was that the @property decorator turns a function into a getter. [You can read more about property() in this SO response.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python)

The solution for me was to access volume_range like a variable and not call it as a function:

```
    def get_oz_range(self, obj):
      return obj.volume_range # No more parenthesis
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: the `'int' object is not callable` error also appears if you accidentally use `.size()` as a method (which does not exist) instead of the `.size` property in Pandas dataframes as demonstrated below. Thus the error can appear in unexpected places.

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([35, 52, 63, 52])
print("unique numbers: ",s.unique())
print("number of unique values: ",s.unique().size())
```