# python error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
import time
a = time.daylight()
print(a)
```

It results in:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Just remove the parens

Comment: you can use print(type(time.daylight)) and it'll tell you want kind of type the attribute is. If it's a function, then you can call it with your parans ()

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 6):

`time.daylight` is a number; do not attempt to call it by putting parentheses at the end.