# Why am I getting a " Traceback (most recent call last):" error?

Tags: python

I'm sorry for asking, but I can't find why I'm getting this errors, especially after the program is running.

The erros to be exact are:

```
>>> 
Welcome! This program will convert measures for you.
Select operation.
1.Miles to Kilometers
2.Fahrenheit to Celsius
3.Gallons to liters
4.Pounds to kilograms
5.Inches to centimeters
Enter your choice by number: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Levhitor\Downloads\Mario_Gomez_Lab2.py", line 112, in <module>
    intro()
  File "C:\Users\Levhitor\Downloads\Mario_Gomez_Lab2.py", line 12, in intro
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Levhitor\Downloads\Mario_Gomez_Lab2.py", line 25, in main
    convertMK()
  File "C:\Users\Levhitor\Downloads\Mario_Gomez_Lab2.py", line 44, in convertMK
    input_M = float(raw_input(("Miles: ")))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I don't understand what's happening here. Can anyone help me?

```
raw_input = 0
M = 1.6
# Miles to Kilometers 
# Celsius Celsius = (var1 - 32) * 5/9
# Gallons to liters Gallons = 3.6
# Pounds to kilograms Pounds = 0.45
# Inches to centimete Inches = 2.54


def intro():
    print("Welcome! This program will convert measures for you.")
    main()

def main():
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Miles to Kilometers")
    print("2.Fahrenheit to Celsius")
    print("3.Gallons to liters")
    print("4.Pounds to kilograms")
    print("5.Inches to centimeters")

    choice = input("Enter your choice by number: ")

    if choice == '1':
        convertMK()

    elif choice == '2':
        converCF()

    elif choice == '3':
        convertGL()

    elif choice == '4':
        convertPK()

    elif choice == '5':
        convertPK()

    else:
        print("Error")


def convertMK():
    input_M = float(raw_input(("Miles: ")))
    M_conv = (M) * input_M
    print("Kilometers: %f\n" % M_conv)
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def converCF():
    input_F = float(raw_input(("Fahrenheit: ")))
    F_conv = (input_F - 32) * 5/9
    print("Celcius: %f\n") % F_conv
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def convertGL():
    input_G = float(raw_input(("Gallons: ")))
    G_conv = input_G * 3.6
    print("Centimeters: %f\n" % G_conv)
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def convertPK():
    input_P = float(raw_input(("Pounds: ")))
    P_conv = input_P * 0.45
    print("Centimeters: %f\n" % P_conv)
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def convertIC():
    input_cm = float(raw_input(("Inches: ")))
    inches_conv = input_cm * 2.54
    print("Centimeters: %f\n" % inches_conv)
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def end():
    print("This program will close.")
    exit()

intro()
```

I do not know what is wrong... can anyone help me? 
Thanks you!

Comment: Deleted the raw_input, It stills throw the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Levhitor/Mario_Gomez_Lab7a.py", line 111, in <module>
    intro()
  File "C:/Users/Levhitor/Mario_Gomez_Lab7a.py", line 11, in intro
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Levhitor/Mario_Gomez_Lab7a.py", line 24, in main
    convertMK()
  File "C:/Users/Levhitor/Mario_Gomez_Lab7a.py", line 43, in convertMK
    input_M = float(raw_input(("Miles: ")))
NameError: global name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: are you by chance using python 3?   in python 3, `raw_input()` is called `input()` (and `input()` is called `eval(input())`, but don't do that)

Comment: Yes, then change the `raw_input()`s to `input()`. And yes, DO NOT USE `eval`! `eval` is evil.

Answer (score 4):

At the beginning of your file you set `raw_input` to 0. Do not do this, at it modifies the built-in `raw_input()` function. Therefore, whenever you call `raw_input()`, it is essentially calling `0()`, which raises the error. To remove the error, remove the first line of your code:

```
M = 1.6
# Miles to Kilometers 
# Celsius Celsius = (var1 - 32) * 5/9
# Gallons to liters Gallons = 3.6
# Pounds to kilograms Pounds = 0.45
# Inches to centimete Inches = 2.54


def intro():
    print("Welcome! This program will convert measures for you.")
    main()

def main():
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Miles to Kilometers")
    print("2.Fahrenheit to Celsius")
    print("3.Gallons to liters")
    print("4.Pounds to kilograms")
    print("5.Inches to centimeters")

    choice = input("Enter your choice by number: ")

    if choice == '1':
        convertMK()

    elif choice == '2':
        converCF()

    elif choice == '3':
        convertGL()

    elif choice == '4':
        convertPK()

    elif choice == '5':
        convertPK()

    else:
        print("Error")


def convertMK():
    input_M = float(raw_input(("Miles: ")))
    M_conv = (M) * input_M
    print("Kilometers: %f\n" % M_conv)
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def converCF():
    input_F = float(raw_input(("Fahrenheit: ")))
    F_conv = (input_F - 32) * 5/9
    print("Celcius: %f\n") % F_conv
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def convertGL():
    input_G = float(raw_input(("Gallons: ")))
    G_conv = input_G * 3.6
    print("Centimeters: %f\n" % G_conv)
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def convertPK():
    input_P = float(raw_input(("Pounds: ")))
    P_conv = input_P * 0.45
    print("Centimeters: %f\n" % P_conv)
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def convertIC():
    input_cm = float(raw_input(("Inches: ")))
    inches_conv = input_cm * 2.54
    print("Centimeters: %f\n" % inches_conv)
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def end():
    print("This program will close.")
    exit()

intro()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version of Python you are using but I tried this in Python 3 and made a few changes and it looks like it works. The raw_input function seems to be the issue here. I changed all the raw_input functions to "input()" and I also made minor changes to the printing to be compatible with Python 3. AJ Uppal is correct when he says that you shouldn't name a variable and a function with the same name. See here for reference:

[TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable)

My code for Python 3 is as follows:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097039/why-am-i-getting-a-traceback-most-recent-call-last-error

raw_input = 0
M = 1.6
# Miles to Kilometers
# Celsius Celsius = (var1 - 32) * 5/9
# Gallons to liters Gallons = 3.6
# Pounds to kilograms Pounds = 0.45
# Inches to centimete Inches = 2.54


def intro():
    print("Welcome! This program will convert measures for you.")
    main()

def main():
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Miles to Kilometers")
    print("2.Fahrenheit to Celsius")
    print("3.Gallons to liters")
    print("4.Pounds to kilograms")
    print("5.Inches to centimeters")

    choice = input("Enter your choice by number: ")

    if choice == '1':
        convertMK()

    elif choice == '2':
        converCF()

    elif choice == '3':
        convertGL()

    elif choice == '4':
        convertPK()

    elif choice == '5':
        convertPK()

    else:
        print("Error")


def convertMK():
    input_M = float(input(("Miles: ")))
    M_conv = (M) * input_M
    print("Kilometers: {M_conv}\n")
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def converCF():
    input_F = float(input(("Fahrenheit: ")))
    F_conv = (input_F - 32) * 5/9
    print("Celcius: {F_conv}\n")
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def convertGL():
    input_G = float(input(("Gallons: ")))
    G_conv = input_G * 3.6
    print("Centimeters: {G_conv}\n")
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def convertPK():
    input_P = float(input(("Pounds: ")))
    P_conv = input_P * 0.45
    print("Centimeters: {P_conv}\n")
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def convertIC():
    input_cm = float(input(("Inches: ")))
    inches_conv = input_cm * 2.54
    print("Centimeters: {inches_conv}\n")
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()

def end():
    print("This program will close.")
    exit()

intro()
```

I noticed a small bug in your code as well. This function should ideally convert pounds to kilograms but it looks like when it prints, it is printing "Centimeters" instead of kilograms.

```
def convertPK():
    input_P = float(input(("Pounds: ")))
    P_conv = input_P * 0.45
    # Printing error in the line below
    print("Centimeters: {P_conv}\n")
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        main()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end()
    else:
        print ("I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating.")
        main()
```

I hope this helps.