# Pyspark sql: Create a new column based on whether a value exists in a different DataFrame's column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161879/pyspark-withcolumn-with-two-conditions-and-three-outcomes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa%22this%20answer%22) but my question is slightly different.

I have two pyspark data frames `df2` and `bears2`. Both have an integer variable, and I want to create a boolean like this pseudocode:

```python
df3 = df2.withColumn("game", (df2.week_id.isin(bears2.week_if), 1,0))
```

Basically, if the value of `df2` exists in the corresponding column of `bears2`, I want a `1` else a `0`

I tried the `expr()` from the other question, but wasn't able to get it to work. It looked like this:

```python
new_column_1 = F.expr(
    """IF(df2.week_id IN(bears2.week_if), 1, 0))"""
    )
```

Comment: you've forgot `withColumn(...., when(condition, value).otherwise(another_value))`

Comment: I tried this based on another answer (which was not deleted). Do I need to convert bears2.week_if into a list/vector for this to work? Because I get an error.

Comment: @mlewis `IN` will not work for dataframes- you'll have to use join. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: `isin` expects list as a parameter. if you want to check with another dataframe - you can do join on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't currently use `IN` like that with pyspark-sql<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34866817/5858851)</sup>. Instead, you will have to join the DataFrames.

Try something like:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when
df3 = df2.withColumn("id", col("week_id")).alias("df2")\
    .join(bears2.withColumn("id", col("week_if")).alias("bears2"), on="id", how="left")\
    .select("df2.*", when(col("bears2.id").isNotNull(), 1).otherwise(0))
```

For the join to work, the join key column has to exist in both DataFrames. For that reason, I first call `withColumn("id", ...)` to rename the columns to the same value for the join.

Next we do a LEFT join to keep all of the columns in `df2`. Finally we select all of the columns in `df2` and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to create the boolean column.

The first argument to `when()` is a condition. If it is `True`, the second argument is returned. If not, the value in `otherwise()` is used.

Comment: The output of the join looks good, but the when statement returns 



`TypeError: condition should be a Column`


Should I try one of the methods in the previous answer of creating the column?

Comment: @mlewis try the update- I changed the sql condition to `isNotNull()` instead.