# Cap a pyspark column by condition on other column?

Tags: pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe

```
x1 x2
12 4
8 5
13 2
```

I would like to cap `x1 = 10` for the rows with `x2 < 5`, something like:

```
if x2 < 5:
  if x1 > 10:
    x1 = 10
```

How could I do that for Pyspark?

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161879/pyspark-withcolumn-with-two-conditions-and-three-outcomes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySpark: withColumn() with two conditions and three outcomes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161879/pyspark-withcolumn-with-two-conditions-and-three-outcomes)

Answer (score 0):

this is the base logic:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df = spark.createDataFrame([(12, 4), (8, 5), (13, 2)]).toDF("x1", "x2")

df\
.withColumn("logic", when(df.x2 < 5, 10)\
            .otherwise(when(df.x1 > 10, 10)))\
.show()

+---+---+-----+
| x1| x2|logic|
+---+---+-----+
| 12|  4|   10|
|  8|  5| null|
| 13|  2|   10|
+---+---+-----+

// other logic

from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lit

df\
.withColumn("logic", when((df.x2 < 5) & (df.x1 > 10), lit(10))\
            .otherwise(df.x1))\
.show()

+---+---+-----+
| x1| x2|logic|
+---+---+-----+
| 12|  4|   10|
|  8|  5|    8|
| 13|  2|   10|
+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: I think your logic is incorrect. it should be `when((df.x2 < 5)&(df.x1 > 10), lit(10)).otherwise(df.x1))` or `when(df.x2 < 5, least(df.x1, lit(10))).otherwise(df.x1))` (after importing `lit`, `when`, and `least` from `pyspark.sql.functions`)

Comment: ok thanks i updated it ... the original question wasn't clear to me