# errors while installing robot framework on windows machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am trying to install robot framework on my windows 10 machine but I am getting below error.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install robotframework
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\charset.py", line 13, in <module>
    import email.base64mimeenter code here
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.utils import fix_eols
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\calendar.py", line 9, in <module>
    cal=calendar.month(str(year),str(month))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I have installed python 2.7.14 before starting robot framework installation.
Kindly suggest a way forward.

Comment: Using Python 2.7.17 (but Windows 7) `pip install robotframework` successfully installed robotframework-3.0.2. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable).

Comment: Can you please share more information about your Python installation and your machine. For example, have you been able to install other modules through PIP or does it not matter which one you install this error is always presented. Does the desktop have to go through a proxy to reach the internet? Does `pip search robotframework` deliver any results?

Comment: I have installed python 2.7.14 on windows 10 machine. looks like pip itself is not working. It is not specific while installing robotframework. the error is always presented. pip search robotframework also fails with the same error.

Comment: This is resolved now by installing pip again by using: python -m pip install -U pip command