# Problem with trying to use the equation for total payoff amount for my python lab

Tags: python

I need help with question 3 found in the link below 
http://courses.cse.tamu.edu/davidkebo/csce-110/labs/lab_2.pdf

```
p = 15000
r = float(input("Enter interest rate (in percentage): "))
n = float(input("Enter loan period (in years): "))
c = p(1+r/100)**n
print()
print(f" At {r}% interest, you need to pay ${c} after {n} years")
```

I don't know why it's telling me that i have an uncallable 'int' or how i'd get the payoff to be rounded to 2 decimal points

Comment: I see two questions here, the first might possibly be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable/9767422 the second could be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `c = p(1+r/100)**n`

Anything with parentheses after it will be regarded as a function call in Python (`p(...)` in your case). You have to explicity give it a multiplication operator. Because `p` is an integer equal to `15000`, you are trying to call an int... hence the error.

Change it to:
`c = p * (1 + r / 100) ** n`

Comment: I appreciate the help! I now realize that i was looking too much into the code and trying to find a huge flaw .

Comment: @Darren Consider accepting this as an answer by clicking the check mark next to it if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages you must explicitly put the multiplication operator when you want to do multiplication: `p*(1+r/100)**n`.

```
c = p * (1+r/100)**n
```

Comment: thank you so much! i was looking for something so drastic that i forgot the basics.