# What does a "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" mean?

Tags: python

```
n = 24
if n % 2 == 0 (n >= 6 and n <= 20):
    print("Weird")
```

...emits the error message:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

What does this mean? How can it be avoided?

Comment: `0 (n >= 6 and n <= 20)` is definitely wrong, but it's not clear what you are trying to do. Please see [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What is the condition `n % 2 == 0 (n >= 6 and n <= 20)` intended to mean?

Comment: BTW, the edits I've made (showing only the *shortest possible code* that demonstrates the problem; pruning prose that isn't necessary to understanding the issue; and making the title descriptive of the specific question) are things you should try to follow in your own questions going forward.

Comment: variable followed by parenthesis is interpreted as calling a function, so `x(...)` is a function call, so is `0(...)`, except that integers aren't callable.

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 2):

You need the `and` or `or` operator to combine the modulus condition and the range condition.

Python also allows you to use chained comparisons to test if a number is in a range.

```
if n % 2 == 0 or 6 <= n <= 20:
```

Answer (score 0):

you are equating the division to 0 and the other condition all together.

you have to separate the steps, equal to zero and then check.

n = 24

if n % 2 == 0:
    print ("Not Weird")
else:
    print ("Weird")

if n % 2 == 0 & (n >= 6 and n <= 20):
    print("Weird")

if n % 2 == 0 & (n <= 2 and n >= 5):
    print("Not Weird")

if n % 2 == 0 & (n > 20):
    print("Not Weird")

Comment: `and` should be used rather than `&` here, since the OP is trying to do a *logical* AND rather than a *bitwise* one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `&` works on booleans, it's just unusual to use it because normally the short-circuiting `and` is better.

Comment: Is there a reason you'd argue that the short-circuiting `and` isn't better in this case?

Comment: The error is happening because OP is writing `0 (n >= 6 and n <= 20)` which is interpreted as "call the `0` method and pass it the result of this boolean operation as an argument" when Python looks to see what `0` is, it finds it is not a `callable` object, but an `int` object, and `int` is not callable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think @kaya3 was suggesting that `&` is better here, just that it *does* work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  is there any performance difference to `and` / `&`?

in the end all logic is done in binary comparation, or not?

Comment: Whole point of short-circuiting is that you avoid running the logic on the RHS if the LHS obviates it. Running less code is generally preferable to running more, particularly if they both get you the same outcome.