# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable when trying to check if any array elements meet a specific condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of integers. If any of them are greater than `threshold` I want it to evaluate as true.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(10)
threshold = 5

if arr.any() > threshold:
    print(arr)
```

[TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable) states I shouldn't name a variable and a function the same thing, I don't think I'm doing that. In the example in the accepted answer `round` is being used as a variable name and as its function.

I tried changing the code in case `arr` or `threshold` is a function I'm not aware of and can't find on google to:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)
b = 5

if a.any() > b():
    print(a)
```

But I get the same error. How do I return `true` if any array elements are > threshold?

Full Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    if a.any() > b():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback from the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you're using the `any()` function wrong.

Switch from

```
if arr.any() > threshold:
    print(arr)
```

to

```
if np.any(arr > threshold):
    print(arr)
```

Comment: Easy! Thank you my dude!