# Please provide support with this Class method example

Tags: python, typeerror

```py
class Person:
    number_of_people = 0

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        Person.add_person()

    @classmethod                        
    def number_of_people_(cls):         
        return cls.number_of_people()

    @classmethod
    def add_person(cls):
        cls.number_of_people += 1

p1 = Person('Tim')
p2 = Person('Jill')
print(Person.number_of_people_())
```

The code above gives

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Please help with this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: No, this didn't help with the error, I'm afraid (or at least it wasn't easily apparent to a coding newbie like me). Please help

Comment: `return cls.number_of_people`

Comment: `number_of_people` is an int, so there is no such thing as `number_of_people()` as that suggests that that int variable is callable (as if it were a method because of the parentheses).

Comment: Ah! That helped immensely. Thank you so much for your prompt explanation!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. In the future, please make a [mre], which will help to catch basic mistakes like this. For more tips, see [ask]. Please note that on this site, we don't "provide support", we answer questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TypeError` is because of what you are trying to return in your classmethod:

```
umber_of_people = 0

def number_of_people_(cls):         
    return cls.number_of_people() # you are calling the attribute above which is set to 0
```

Change to:

```
def number_of_people_(cls):         
    return cls.number_of_people
```