# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: sum, integer, typeerror

```
sum = 0 
my_sum = sum([i*2 for i in range(2, 196)])
```

I have an TypeError: `int object is not callable` for the code above.

What I am doing wrong?

The code before was like that:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(2, 196):
    sum = sum + i
 print(sum)
```

I am trying to sum up the squares of the integers instead of just the integers.

Comment: And which programing language you using?

Answer (score 1):

As r_mchugh suggested, sum() is a built-in function in Python. sum = 0 will override sum() as int to cause it uncallable anymore. It can be fixed simply remove sum = 0. Your old code didn't cause trouble is because you didn't call sum() otherwise it will raise same error. The correct one should be like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is python and I believe it's because you are trying to use the sum function with a declared variable named 'sum' equal to 0 (which defaults to 'int'), you cannot declare a variable with the same name as the built-in function, it overrides it with the variable in the program.

refer to: [TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable)